# Traduções na janela de captcha

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Comecei a fazer uma pergunta ontem que só acabei de escrever hoje, o que fez com que o *sistema* me apresentasse a janela para introdução de um código de verificação assim que cliquei em "Publicar":

[image: Verificação Captcha]

Na mesma existem algumas coisas que podem ser melhoradas:

1. **O título da janela**

   Atualmente o título está em Inglês, mas dado o restante conteúdo já se encontrar traduzido, o mesmo deveria ficar em Português:

   > Verificação Humana

   ou

   > Verificação de presença humana
2. **Último paragrafo do texto**

   Este último paragrafo parece-me um pouco estranho, talvez utilize uma construção mais "normal" no Brasil, ou uma tradução demasiado direta em relação ao texto em Inglês. Contudo sugeria simplificar e indicar a localização correta da área de captcha:

   > Insira o CAPTCHA exibido ao lado para prosseguir.